# Math in TV: What episode of law & order is "the eigenvalue is off" from?

Tags: popular-math

I'm trying to compile some clips of math in popular culture to save for various math talks I give. I know that in some episode of law and order, detective Max Greevey (he is only in season 1 I believe) makes the statement "the eigenvalue is off", but I can't find the clip anywhere. What episode does this occur in?

Note: this question actually fits the description in the MSE sidebar (although perhaps it would be more appropriate in the movie/tv stack exchange).

Comment: Isn't what you asked for, but maybe still useful for you ;)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4SBMyd0yEQ

Comment: @Luca That actually is what I was looking for haha. I got it mixed up with law and order. You want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No Way Out (1987) - Fourier scene: youtube.com/watch?v=m4SBMyd0yEQ

Here you go :)